# Successful (non YA) epic high fantasy published episodically as a novella series

Tags: fantasy, self-publishing, series, novella

The high fantasy genre is notorious for producing enormous tomes.

I am currently writing a **BronzePunk** epic of my own. However, I have chosen to publish it somewhat episodically as a series of novellas / short novels of between **30k and 35k word length** so this is **NOT** the same as publishing individual chapters. Each is 50:50 stand alone / part of the series (neither 'completely stand alone' nor 'just another chapter in the action'). Having already published the first three episodes (as presented on [my blog & website](https://charlesgull.mobi)), I have received positive feedback from readers and critics with Star ratings averaging between 4.0 and 4.5 on Amazon and Goodreads *(all from strangers as I have studiously avoided campaigning amongst friends and family)*. However, over a year after publishing the first book and following targeted and focused marketing efforts, sales remain very low *(total combined sales of ebook and paperback for all three episodes about 200 copies so far)*.

I am beginning to wonder if my basic format choice is doomed to failure. Perhaps, I should write more of the story in one go and publish it as a 300k word house brick all at once. In the age of the ebook, larger books don't suffer from weight and size inconvenience so much any more. However, un-known indie-authors are often advised to keep their debuts short.

What examples of long running and successful *(principally judged by commercial metrics)* epic high fantasy series released episodically in shorter formats are there?

For bonus kudos the answers should ideally be **Adult / Grimmdark / non-graphic & non-light / High Fantasy**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Self-Publishing Chapters](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/46808/self-publishing-chapters)

Comment: @motosubatsu, not directly, no. I am talking about story slices of between 30k and 35k words. These are both: much longer than individual chapters; more stand alone than individual chapters. Think more along the lines of 'Linked Stories'.

Comment: this is probably closer to the model followed by J.S. Morin then (I'm thinking particularly of his *Black Ocean* series which seems to have done reasonably well. His are available both singularly and in bundles in order to satisfy both short and long forms.

Comment: @motosubatsu, J.S.Morin does indeed appear to be employing a similar model. First individual releases for a certain number of books and then re-release as a bundle. Interestingly, The _Black Ocean_ series is about the same size per book, but principally _Sci-Fi_. He also does the same with _Fantasy_, but their the individual books appear to be 2 to 3 times longer. Again, an indication that High Fantasy demands longer works from the get go.

Comment: Are those novellas a self-contained stories, or episodes which can't be enjoyed out of context of other novellas?

Comment: @Alexander, My _INTENTION_ was to achieve a little bit of both. Read together, each book does indeed contribute a small segment of a central overarching plot. However, taken individually, each is a unique character portrait told in first person present. Because of the size and complexity of the world I have envisioned, I am leveraging the unreliable narrator to avoid large scale block exposition. Each book only presents the sub-set of aspects of the world relevant to that particular PoV.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a list of works, which is off-topic.

Comment: It seems to me that you've already had your debut on Amazon? So one option could be to pause/finish the current project and take on a new one with a full-length story to see where that goes? It's very hard to pinpoint success factors in writing. You have very accomplished authors and stories that don't want to take off... and then you have Fifty Shades of Grey... ;) So keep at it, change a bit, learn a bit, publish, publish, publish... would be my advice...